# How to print returned object Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I use `requests` library in my custom function:

```
def add_advert(self, json_data):
       headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
       return requests.post(self.base_url + self.api_urls["add_advert"], 
  json=json_data, headers=headers,
                          auth=(self.api_key, ''))
```

And call this function:

```
response = api.add_advert(json_data=json_data)
```

How to show content from variable `response`?

I tried: print `response.content`, print `response.json`

Comment: what does `print response` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "content" you want to show is the response payload... `response.text`

or

`response.json()` - `.json` is a function (assumes json payload)

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content